# my carousel is just flashing each image and not waiting the slide time before switching over to the next slide

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

my carousel is just flashing each image  and not waiting the slide time before switching over to the next slide. what am i doing wrong? I know my html is correct so it is not included

```
<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel-wrapper">
    <a href="/vedoors" class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/frontPageDoors.jpg" alt="VE Doors">
    </a>
    <a href="/micromarkets" class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/FrontPageKiosks.jpg" alt="VE Kiosks">
    </a>
    <a href="/venture" class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/FrontPageVenture.jpg" alt="VE Venture">
    </a>
    <a href="/Vepass" class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/FrontPagePass.jpg" alt="VE Pass">
    </a>
    <a href="/ucb-product-page" class="carousel-item">
      <img src="images/FrontPage UCB.jpg" alt="The UCB">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-controls">
<button class="carousel-control prev" aria-label="Previous">&#10094;</button>
<button class="carousel-control next" aria-label="Next">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.carousel-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 500%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.carousel-item {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-item-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.carousel-controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
  left: 10px;
  right: auto;
}

.carousel-control.next {
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
</style>

<script>
const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel-wrapper');
const carouselItems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.carousel-control.prev');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.carousel-control.next');
const slideTime = 10000; // time in ms for each slide

let slideIndex = 0;
let intervalId;

function startSlide() {
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    slideNext(); // Call the slideNext function for auto-scrolling
  }, slideTime);
}

function pauseSlide() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}

function slidePrev() {
  slideIndex = (slideIndex - 1 + carouselItems.length) % carouselItems.length;
  carousel.style.transform = `translateX(-${slideIndex * (100 / carouselItems.length)}%)`;
}

function slideNext() {
  slideIndex = (slideIndex + 1) % carouselItems.length;
  carousel.style.transform = `translateX(-${slideIndex * (100 / carouselItems.length)}%)`;
}

startSlide();

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  pauseSlide();
  slidePrev();
  setTimeout(startSlide, slideTime);
});

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  pauseSlide();
  slideNext();
  setTimeout(startSlide, slideTime);
});

carousel.addEventListener('mouseover', pauseSlide);
carousel.addEventListener('mouseout', startSlide);

</script>
```

i tried to make it take 10 seconds per slide and its just zooming trhrough in miliseconds, not even waiting like i asked it to

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: can you add your html also ? try to create runnable example --> [how to minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: html added for those who asked

Answer (score 0):

One issue I can see in your code is that in your event listener's functionality for `nextBtn` and `prevBtn` you are calling `startSlide` function in a `setTimeout`.

Now as the `startSlide` function has a `setInterval` in it which should be called after 10sec. Now when you are `startSlide` function with the prev and next button click it is running a new instance of `setInterval` each time and this triggering of multiple `setInterval` may cause this flashing.

Now you can either remove the `setTimeout(startSlide, slideTime);` from prev and next button event listener or you can send only the `nextSlide` function in `setTimeout` instead of the full `startSlide`

```js
  prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pauseSlide();
    slidePrev();
    setTimeout(slideNext, slideTime); //<- this call
  });

  nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pauseSlide();
    slideNext();
    setTimeout(slideNext, slideTime); //<- this call
  });
```

Try this out I hope it will be helpful to solve your issue.